# Given a logfile.txt, I want to extract the java script name only; e.g. filename.js using a bash script

Tags: bash, awk, cut, text-manipulation

I use following awk script to do so,

```
for line in $1
do
 grep -F ".js" $1 | awk '{print $7}' | sort -u 
done
```

the out put is almost there:

```
/blog/wp-includes/js/swfobject.js?ver=2.2
/fla/AC_RunActiveContent.js
/include/jquery.js
/include/jquery.jshowoff2.js
/include/jquery.jshowoff.min.js
/include/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js
/scripts/ac_runactivecontent.js
```

I tried piping: cut -d "/" -f5 intead of awk, but parts of script name are cut off as well.

```
ac_runactivecontent.js HTTP
AC_RunActiveContent.js HTTP
jquery.jshowoff2.js HTTP
jquery.jshowoff.min.js HTTP
jquery.js HTTP
js
wp-includes
```

How would I go about extracting from the pattern .js to the delimiter "/" so that I only get the script file name:

```
swfobject.js
AC_RunActiveContent.js
jquery.js
jquery.jshowoff2.js
jquery.jshowoff.min.js
jquery.lightbox-0.5.js
ac_runactivecontent.js
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably going to be more efficient to look at replacing the current `for/grep/awk/sort` with a single `awk` (and optional `sort`).

Setup:

```
$ cat filename.js
1 2 3 4 5 6 /blog/wp-includes/js/swfobject.js?ver=2.2 8 9 10
ignore this line
1 2 3 4 5 6 /fla/AC_RunActiveContent.js 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 /include/jquery.js 8 9 10
ignore this line
1 2 3 4 5 6 /include/jquery.jshowoff2.js 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 /include/jquery.jshowoff.min.js 8 9 10
ignore this line
1 2 3 4 5 6 /include/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 /scripts/ac_runactivecontent.js 8 9 10
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
/.js/ { n=split($7,a,"[/?]")          # split field #7 on dual characters "/" and "?", putting substrings into array a[]
        for (i=n;i>=1;i--)            # assuming desired string is toward end of $7 we will work backward through the array
        if (a[i] ~ ".js") {           # if we find a match then ...
           print a[i]                 # print it and break out of the loop ...
           next                       # by going to next input record
        }
      }
' filename.js

# or as a single line:

awk '/.js/ {n=split($7,a,"[/?]"); for (i=n;i>=1;i--) if (a[i] ~ ".js") { print a[i]; next}}' filename.js
```

This generates:

```
swfobject.js
AC_RunActiveContent.js
jquery.js
jquery.jshowoff2.js
jquery.jshowoff.min.js
jquery.lightbox-0.5.js
ac_runactivecontent.js
```

**NOTE:** OP can pipe the results to `sort` if desired

Comment: Thank you @markp-fuso your answer let me understand the "awk" command better and its versatility.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` you could print the match for the filename from the 7th column.

The pattern `[^/]+\.js` matches 1+ times any character except `/` followed by matching `.js`

Using for example a `file` as input:

```
awk '
match($7, /[^/]+\.js/) {
  print substr($7, RSTART, RLENGTH)
}
' file
```

Output

```
swfobject.js
AC_RunActiveContent.js
jquery.js
jquery.jshowoff2.js
jquery.jshowoff.min.js
jquery.lightbox-0.5.js
ac_runactivecontent.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using `awk`, the answer provided by @markp-fuso is probably your best option.  If you are open to other options, you may be able to use a combination of `grep` and `basename`.   (Note that this will likely be less efficient due to piping `grep` output to `basename`)

Using the sample file from the answer provided by @markp-fuso, the following:

```
grep -o ' /.*\.js' tt.dat | xargs basename
```

Produces the following output:

```
swfobject.js
AC_RunActiveContent.js
jquery.js
jquery.jshowoff2.js
jquery.jshowoff.min.js
jquery.lightbox-0.5.js
ac_runactivecontent.js
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

`basename`

and

`man basename`

command.